# Reuse Reusing Variable of LSTM in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I'm trying to make `RNN` using `LSTM`.
I made `LSTM` model, and after it, there is two `DNN` network, and one regression output layer.

I trained my data, and the final training loss become about `0.009`.
However, when i applied the model to test data, the loss become about `0.5`.

The 1th epoch training loss is about `0.5`.
***So, I think the trained variable do not used in test model.***

The only difference between training and test model is batch size.
`Trainning Batch = 100~200`, `Test Batch Size = 1`.

in main function i made `LSTM` instance.
In `LSTM` innitializer, the model is made.

```
def __init__(self,config,train_model=None):
    self.sess = sess = tf.Session()

    self.num_steps = num_steps = config.num_steps
    self.lstm_size = lstm_size = config.lstm_size
    self.num_features = num_features = config.num_features
    self.num_layers = num_layers = config.num_layers
    self.num_hiddens = num_hiddens = config.num_hiddens
    self.batch_size = batch_size = config.batch_size
    self.train = train = config.train
    self.epoch = config.epoch
    self.learning_rate = learning_rate = config.learning_rate

    with tf.variable_scope('model') as scope:        
        self.lstm_cell = lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(lstm_size,initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False))
        self.cell = cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell] * num_layers)

    with tf.name_scope('placeholders'):
        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[self.batch_size,num_steps,num_features],
                                name='input-x')
        self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [self.batch_size,num_features],name='input-y')
        self.init_state = cell.zero_state(self.batch_size,tf.float32)
    with tf.variable_scope('model'):
        self.W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([lstm_size*num_steps,num_hiddens],stddev=0.1),name='W1')
        self.b1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hiddens],stddev=0.1),name='b1')
        self.W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hiddens,num_hiddens],stddev=0.1),name='W2')
        self.b2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hiddens],stddev=0.1),name='b2')
        self.W3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hiddens,num_features],stddev=0.1),name='W3')
        self.b3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_features],stddev=0.1),name='b3')


    self.output, self.loss = self.inference()
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run(session=sess)                
    tf.initialize_variables([self.b2]).run(session=sess)

    if train_model == None:
        self.train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.learning_rate).minimize(self.loss)
```

Using Above LSTM **init**, below LSTM instance are made.

```
with tf.variable_scope("model",reuse=None):
    train_model = LSTM(main_config)
with tf.variable_scope("model", reuse=True):
    predict_model = LSTM(predict_config)
```

after making two `LSTM` instance, I trained the `train_model`.
And I input the test set in `predict_model`.

Why the variable are not reused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you should be using `tf.get_variable()` to create your variables, instead of `tf.Variable()`, if you are reusing a `scope`.

Take a look [at this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/variable_scope/index.html) for sharing variables, you'll understand it better.

Also, you don't need to use a session here, because you don't have to initialize your variables when you are defining the model, the variables should be initialized when you are about to train your model.

The code to reuse the variables is the following:

```
def __init__(self,config,train_model=None):
    self.num_steps = num_steps = config.num_steps
    self.lstm_size = lstm_size = config.lstm_size
    self.num_features = num_features = config.num_features
    self.num_layers = num_layers = config.num_layers
    self.num_hiddens = num_hiddens = config.num_hiddens
    self.batch_size = batch_size = config.batch_size
    self.train = train = config.train
    self.epoch = config.epoch
    self.learning_rate = learning_rate = config.learning_rate

    with tf.variable_scope('model') as scope:        
        self.lstm_cell = lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(lstm_size,initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False))
        self.cell = cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell] * num_layers)

    with tf.name_scope('placeholders'):
        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[self.batch_size,num_steps,num_features],
                                name='input-x')
        self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [self.batch_size,num_features],name='input-y')
        self.init_state = cell.zero_state(self.batch_size,tf.float32)
    with tf.variable_scope('model'):
        self.W1 = tf.get_variable(initializer=tf.truncated_normal([lstm_size*num_steps,num_hiddens],stddev=0.1),name='W1')
        self.b1 = tf.get_variable(initializer=tf.truncated_normal([num_hiddens],stddev=0.1),name='b1')
        self.W2 = tf.get_variable(initializer=tf.truncated_normal([num_hiddens,num_hiddens],stddev=0.1),name='W2')
        self.b2 = tf.get_variable(initializer=tf.truncated_normal([num_hiddens],stddev=0.1),name='b2')
        self.W3 = tf.get_variable(initializer=tf.truncated_normal([num_hiddens,num_features],stddev=0.1),name='W3')
        self.b3 = tf.get_variable(initializer=tf.truncated_normal([num_features],stddev=0.1),name='b3')


    self.output, self.loss = self.inference()

    if train_model == None:
        self.train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.learning_rate).minimize(self.loss)
```

To see which variables are created after you create `train_model` and `predict_model` use the following code:

```
for v in tf.all_variables():
    print(v.name)
```