# Tensorflow NotFoundError

Tags: python, tensorflow, sequence-to-sequence

I'm running a custom code to train my own Seq2Seq model on tensorflow. I'm using multi-rnn cells and embedding_attention_seq2seq. While restoring the model I get the following error:

```
2017-07-14 13:49:13.693612: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key embedding_attention_seq2seq/rnn/embedding_wrapper/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/basic_lstm_cell/kernel not found in checkpoint
2017-07-14 13:49:13.694491: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key embedding_attention_seq2seq/rnn/embedding_wrapper/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/basic_lstm_cell/bias not found in checkpoint
2017-07-14 13:49:13.695334: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key embedding_attention_seq2seq/rnn/embedding_wrapper/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/kernel not found in checkpoint
2017-07-14 13:49:13.696273: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key embedding_attention_seq2seq/rnn/embedding_wrapper/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/bias not found in checkpoint
2017-07-14 13:49:13.707633: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/Attention_0/bias not found in checkpoint
2017-07-14 13:49:13.707856: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/Attention_0/kernel not found in checkpoint
2017-07-14 13:49:13.709639: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/AttnOutputProjection/kernel not found in checkpoint
2017-07-14 13:49:13.709716: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/AttnOutputProjection/bias not found in checkpoint
2017-07-14 13:49:13.710975: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/bias not found in checkpoint
2017-07-14 13:49:13.711937: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/kernel not found in checkpoint
2017-07-14 13:49:13.712830: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/output_projection_wrapper/bias not found in checkpoint
2017-07-14 13:49:13.713814: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/output_projection_wrapper/kernel not found in checkpoint
2017-07-14 13:49:13.714627: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/output_projection_wrapper/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/bias not found in checkpoint
2017-07-14 13:49:13.715429: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/output_projection_wrapper/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_lstm_cell/kernel not found in checkpoint
2017-07-14 13:49:13.716223: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/output_projection_wrapper/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/basic_lstm_cell/bias not found in checkpoint
2017-07-14 13:49:13.717130: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Not found: Key embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/output_projection_wrapper/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/basic_lstm_cell/kernel not found in checkpoint
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1139, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1121, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 89, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Key embedding_attention_seq2seq/rnn/embedding_wrapper/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/basic_lstm_cell/kernel not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_20 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2_20/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_20/shape_and_slices)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict.py", line 61, in <module>
    pm.saver.restore(sess, "phnet_s2s_bucket1-399")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1548, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 789, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 997, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1132, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1152, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Key embedding_attention_seq2seq/rnn/embedding_wrapper/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/basic_lstm_cell/kernel not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_20 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2_20/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_20/shape_and_slices)]]

Caused by op 'save/RestoreV2_20', defined at:
  File "predict.py", line 60, in <module>
    pm = PredictModel(diction_url="train/train_words_buckets.p")
  File "predict.py", line 35, in __init__
    self.saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1139, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1170, in build
    restore_sequentially=self._restore_sequentially)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 691, in build
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 407, in _AddRestoreOps
    tensors = self.restore_op(filename_tensor, saveable, preferred_shard)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 247, in restore_op
    [spec.tensor.dtype])[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 640, in restore_v2
    dtypes=dtypes, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2506, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1269, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key embedding_attention_seq2seq/rnn/embedding_wrapper/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/basic_lstm_cell/kernel not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_20 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2_20/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_20/shape_and_slices)]]
```

I've followed the similar graph steps as the tutorial on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found the solution. In my code, calling of the RNN cell was inside a variable scope whereas I didn't create the RNN cell in the same scope. It trained just fine but while restoring the model, it failed. 
More details can be found here: [Reuse Reusing Variable of LSTM in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39101512/reuse-reusing-variable-of-lstm-in-tensorflow)